Boy and girl sucked into a black and white world
There was this movie that I watched in school a while ago it went like this. There were two kids, a boy and a girl, that got a tv remote and when they pressed a certain button they got sucked into this cartoon and couldn't get out.
After a couple of days the boy kisses a girl or the girl kisses a boy, and after that the world starts to become colorful and the girl ends up staying in this world and the boy returned to the real world.
The only other thing that I can think of is that in the real world the boy was popular and the girl wasn't but in the black and white world the girl became popular while the boy did not. I think it was a 90's movie but I am unsure of that.

You'll need to try and provide more information than that. What year or at least decade is the movie from? Any other details about the story that you can recall?

The only other thing that I can think of is that in the real world the boy was popular and the girl wasn't but in the cartoon world the girl became popular while the boy did not. I think it was a 90's movie but I am unsure of that.

I know the OP thought this was animated but it is NOT... as it seems to be Pleasantville... should the animated tag be removed? Is this the sort of thing that should be asked on Meta? Generally, should inappropriate tags be removed when the question is answered.

@Catija Probably not. When he thinks it's animated, then that's part of his question. If that turns out to be wrong, we're not supposed to alter the question to fit to the answers. That's not different from adding a "[SOLVED]" appendage to the question title. Though, in this particular case it is not entirely clear if the tag was originally intended to express that the searched movie was animated or if it was simply added for lack of tagging experience and the fact that a cartoon supposedly played a role at some part of the movie.

@NapoleonWilson I understand not changing the question to suit the answers... on one of the other stacks I frequent, particularly, it can become very problematic, but if the purpose of the tags is to help people find similar questions, wouldn't this be (have been, since the tag was removed) mis-categorized?

@Catija If someone has a similar question, then wouldn't he be looking for an animation, too? It wouldn't be a similar question otherwise, would it? (But alas, when does someone search for an ID question at all anyway?)

@NapoleonWilson Other than the false-color, I don't think that most people would confuse Pleasantville (which is completely live-action) with something like Cool World, which is both animated and live action. I'm popping this over to a question on Meta, I think it will a better place to discuss.

@Catija The problem here is (and that might be a bit inherent to ID questions specifically), the people looking for similar questions are not looking for Pleasantville, they're looking for the same question. That is why we're not just supposed to alter the question exactly match the answer, because that's not the original question anymore. Otherwise we could just edit the accepted answer into any question right away. If that valid and applied SE policy of keeping questions be questions is contributory to searchability and long-term value of ID questions is an entirely different problem, though

@Catija That is also the reason why an accepted answer is not enough to retract a "not enough detail" close-vote. It's always the question that matters and not its answers.

@NapoleonWilson I've some more info to the question and reworded the title a bit that should help narrow it down.  I believe that it's reasonable to reopen it now.  As such I've cast a reopen vote.

I believe you are thinking about the movie Pleasantville.
A brother and his sister are sucked into a 50ies TV show where everything is black and white. They got a remote control that started the process. In the show world everything seems like a positive cliché world without real problems (the firemen don't know how to handle fire, they are just saving kittens from trees) but dull and uninspiring. After the sister, who contrary to the brother disliked the world at first, falls in love, emotions begin to develop even with the other citizens. People who learned about emotions start to be in color. At the end the brother leaves but the sister stays.
The TV show world was not animated but it had an artificial look and feel, not only because it was black and white but it was very clean and smooth. But it was not animated in the meaning of drawn or pure CGI.

YESS thank you so much. With out that answer I probably wouldn't be able to go to sleep. Thank you!!!
